# How to add button between listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to put button between two list view which are vertically aligned.Can someone please help me out with the problem.I am very new to android ,I don't have any idea how to do that.

I want to put two small button in the space available between two columns.Please find the below xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.edkul.vimal.edkul.Library"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/library"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView27">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#88FF0000">
        </ListView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#88FF0000">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Please find the below image as a reference.]

Comment: I think this is not your Whole layout code Some starting tags are missing. So pls post Whole layout code with proper format.

Comment: what is your parent layout ? please post the whole xml file. code is missing here .

Comment: Pls explain more where should be the button you want in between listview at bottom or exactly in between both listview. Pls specify.

Comment: @jaydroider I have update xml code.

Comment: @jaydroider thanks .I have replaced with ur code .But I need two button.One more button below button button1

Comment: @jaydroider Thanks It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try with this.**

**Replace this full code in your XML.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.edkul.vimal.edkul.Library">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Library"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="25sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#88FF0000"></ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#88FF0000"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**It will show you button exactly between your listviews.**

**Surely it will help you.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I have replaced my code with this but I need two button on the screen.I need one more button below the button Button1

Answer (score 0):

Make the layout orientation as horizontal .use your first list views and button as 3views in your layout .
Make height as match parent for listviews but wrap content for button .
Check if it works